# What's the fastest way to INSERT loads of data from one table to another? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk

I'm basically trying to copy data from a table in one database in SQL Server 2005 to another table, with the same structure (but lots of indexes) in another database in the same SQL Server instance.

My current approach is the obvious INSERT/SELECT:

```
set identity_insert TargetDBName.dbo.TableName on

insert into TargetDBName.dbo.TableName ([FieldsList])
  select [FieldsList] from  TargetDBName.dbo.TableName    

set identity_insert SourceDBName.dbo.TableName off
```

Which takes, approximately, forever (1 hour for 10 million records, while it took 20 minutes to do it from the table with indexes to the one without them).

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe your indexes will be recalculated on every insert, you should try disabling the indexes, perform bulk insert then enable them again. See if that works

```
----Disable Index
ALTER INDEX [*INDEX_NAME*] ON *TABLE_NAME* DISABLE
GO
----Enable Index
ALTER INDEX [*INDEX_NAME*] ON *TABLE_NAME* REBUILD
GO
```

Comment: Might want to format that a bit better, right now everything above the second "ALTER INDEX" is going to be commented out.

Comment: I agree... disable or drop/add the indexes to your destination during the load.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864341/move-sql-server-data-in-limited-1000-row-chunks)

That should help you insert the data into chunks of 1000. I also like the 'disabling index idea'