# Move SQL Server data in limited (1000 row) chunks to different tables on a monthly basis

Tags: sql-server-2008, move, sql-delete, datepart

I'm looking for a solution how I can move rows from a large table in chunks of 1000 to different tables based on parts of a datetime value (as a monthly archive). I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Remus Rusanu provided the following solution here on stackoverflow [Move SQL Server data in limited (1000 row) chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864341/move-sql-server-data-in-limited-1000-row-chunks) for moving rows in chunks. Works like a charm :-)

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WITH messages AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 id, messageDatetime, message 
        FROM DemoData)
    DELETE messages
        OUTPUT DELETED.id, messageDatetime, message
        INTO messageArchive;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END
```

What I need now ist the ability to move the rows to different tables depending on the month part of the messageDate.

- messages from september should be inserted into a table named messageArchive_09
- messages from october should be inserted into a table named messageArchive_10
- ...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just repeat the code you have 12 times with a where clause using [month()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) and a different target table. I know, copy and paste code feels bad, the alternative is to do something [dynamic](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WITH messages AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 id, messageDatetime, message 
        FROM DemoData
        WHERE month(messageDatetime) = 1)
    DELETE messages
        OUTPUT DELETED.id, DELETED.messageDatetime, DELETED.message
        INTO messageArchive_01;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WITH messages AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 id, messageDatetime, message 
        FROM DemoData
        WHERE month(messageDatetime) = 2)
    DELETE messages
        OUTPUT DELETED.id, DELETED.messageDatetime, DELETED.message
        INTO messageArchive_02;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END
```

Some code to use if you want to go dynamics

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @Template nvarchar(max) ='
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WITH messages AS (
    SELECT TOP 1000 id, messageDatetime, message 
        FROM DemoData
        WHERE month(messageDatetime) = <MONTH>)
    DELETE messages
        OUTPUT DELETED.id, DELETED.messageDatetime, DELETED.message
        INTO <TABLENAME>;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BREAK;
END'

declare @I int = 1

while @I <= 12
begin
  set @sql = replace(@Template, '<TABLENAME>', 'messageArchive_'+right(100+@I, 2))
  set @sql = replace(@sql, '<MONTH>', @I)

  exec (@sql)

  set @I += 1
end
```

Comment: +1 - Hard coding is the way to go.  Even in dynamic SQL he would need to hard-code the translation values, or do a datetime comparison on every row.